# What openings can I play against most openings?

Tags: opening, theory, kings-indian

I'm looking for a "universal" opening. One example is the King's Indian, which you can play against e4, d4, and several other openings. What other openings, for Black or White, can be played versus most classical openings?

Comment: Why though? Just because the lines against e4 and d4 have the same "name", it doesn't mean you won't have to prepare agianst both options.

Comment: Technically "The Hippo" is an answer (e6,d6,g6,b6,a6,h6,Bg7,Bb7,Ne7,Nd7...and if you castle next move, you haven't understood the concept :P) but I can't say I would recommend...

Comment: Just curious what you think the benefit of this is. I'm trying to understand why multiple variations of one opening would be better than single variations of multiple openings. Seems a horse apiece to me, so I'm wondering where I'm wrong.

Answer (score 2):

If you like the King's Indian with black I see no problem with going with the [King's Indian Attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/King%27s_Indian_Attack) with white.

Also, for those who want an opening that fits all black responses the [London System](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/London_System) seems the way to go.

Comment: You'll always play an opening under the same name, but lines where Black plays ...d5 have nothing to do with lines were he doesn't, so I'd say the London System is at least two diffrent opening types.

Answer (score 1):

As white the task is much easier because you make the first move and dictate terms.

You have:

- 1. g4 The Grob
- 1. f4 Bird's
- 1. Nf3 Reti
- 1. b3
- 1. b4 Sokolosky

As black you are more limited and have to play much more passively to be able to play the same moves against almost any white response.

The [Hedgehog](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hedgehog_(chess)) where you play to try and reach this kind of position:

```
 [fen "2r1r1k1/1bqnbppp/pp1ppn2/8/2P1P3/8/PP3PPP/8 b - - 0 1"]
```

The Hippopotamus which looks like this ([Don't mess with the Hippo!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pdAthyBbN7c&ab_channel=EricRosen)):

```
 [fen "r2qk2r/1bpnnpb1/pp1pp1pp/8/8/8/8/8 b - - 0 1"]
```